# Should it stand that $\gcd(f(x), g(x))=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If we have an ideal of the form $I=\langle f(x), g(x)\rangle\subseteq\Bbb Z[x] $ should it stand that $I=\langle \gcd(f(x),g(x))\rangle$?

For example, if we have the ideal $I=\langle 2,x \rangle $ does it stand that $\gcd(2,x)=1$? Or does it not stand necessarily?

Comment: According to the definition of an ideal, no, it doesn't have to stand.

Comment: If $f(x)|g(x)$, then $I = \langle f(x), g(x)\rangle = \langle f(x) \rangle$, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @AWertheim you mean $I=\langle f(x)\rangle$.

Comment: Your question asks two different things, one is about divisiblity, the other is about gcds. Can you clarify exactly which one you mean?

Comment: @AdamHughes I want to know the $\gcd$ of $2$ and $x$, at the example. Is it $$\gcd(2,x)=1$$ or $$\gcd(2,x)=1 \text{ or } 2$$

Comment: @AWertheim I want to know the $\gcd$ of $2$ and $x$, at the example. Is it $$\gcd(2,x)=1$$ or $$\gcd(2,x)=1 \text{ or } 2$$

Comment: @daOnlyBG I want to know the $\gcd$ of $2$ and $x$, at the example. Is it $$\gcd(2,x)=1$$ or $$\gcd(2,x)=1 \text{ or } 2$$

Comment: @user159870 you don't need to reply to every person. Since your question has two different meanings, I've edited it to be just the gcd question.

Comment: The gcd of $2$ and $x$ cannot be $2$, since $2$ is not a divisor of both.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal $(2,x)\subseteq\Bbb Z[x]$ is indeed $1$, since $1|2$ and $1|x$ and any polynomial dividing the irreducible $x$ would have to be a constant and a unit since it is monic. However $2\not |x$ so the gcd cannot be $2$. In particular, $(2,x)$ is not $(1)$ since $\Bbb Z[x]/(1)\cong 0$ but $\Bbb Z[x]/(2,x)=\Bbb F_2$ is the field with two elements.

---

**Addendum**

To see that $\Bbb Z[x]/(2,x)\cong\Bbb F_2$ we just use the definition of quotienting.

Let $t(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ then by definition if

$$t(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k t_nx^n$$

modulo $(2,x)$ we have that $x\equiv 0$ so $t(x)\equiv t_0\mod (2,x)$, also since $2\equiv 0$ we have that $t_0\equiv r\mod (2,x)$ with $r\in \{0,1\}$. So $\Bbb Z[x]/(2,x)\subseteq \Bbb F_2$ is a subring. We show it is non-trivial

*Proof:* Let $q(x),s(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $xq(x)+2s(x)=1$, then since $q(0)=0$ it must be that the constant term of $s$ is ${1\over 2}$ which is obviously a contradiction, so no such polynomials exist, and $1$ is not a polynomial combination of $x$ and $2$ hence $1\not\in(2,x)$, and so it has a non-trivial image in $\Bbb F_2$ so that the map $\Bbb Z[x]/(2,x)\to \Bbb F_2$ is surjective.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, brain fart, it should be fixed now.

Comment: The first sentence doesn't seem to mean too much, however.

Comment: @AdamHughes Ok! Thanks for the answer! One more question. How do we know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x)=\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: @user159870 that's a bit long, I'll add it into my answer rather than respond in comments. Check back in 2-5 minutes

Comment: @AdamHughes Ok. I'll be waiting!

Comment: @user159870 It's done now.

Comment: @AdamHughes I want to clarify one thing. Does it have a non-trivial image because $1 \notin (2,x)$ ?

Comment: @user159870 Yes, that's exactly the point.

Comment: @AdamHughes Hmm... I got stuck... Why would it be the trivial image if $1 \in (2,x)$ ?

Comment: Because then $(1)\subseteq (2,x)\subseteq\Bbb Z[x]=(1)$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no, I'm saying that the op's suggestion that $1\in(2,x)$ would imply that $(1)=(2,x)$ which is a contradiction (as you also note). The "Because then" was meant to imply that what follows would be a consequence of $1\in (2,x)$, and indicate the contradiction that would follow.

Comment: Ok. I see the context now.

Comment: @AdamHughes Can you have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020633/quotientring-show-the-isomorphism?noredirect=1#comment2082620_1020633 I tried to apply the way you showed the isomorphism at an other example. Is it correct? Could I improve somrething?

Comment: @user159870 You show that $\Bbb C[x,y]/\langle x,y\rangle\subseteq\Bbb C$, but you need to also say that $x,y\not |a$ for any $a\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ because of degree things to get the surjectivity.

Comment: @AdamHughes Do I choose for example $a=1$ as you did?

Comment: Oops, sorry, that should be $x,y\not |a$ for any $a\in\Bbb C$.