# Quotientring-Show the isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

To show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x,y \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}$ I did:

$p(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

$p(x,y)=\sum_{m,n=0}^k a_{mn}x^m y^n$

modulo $\langle x, y \rangle$ we have that $x \equiv 0$ and $y \equiv 0$

So $p(x,y)=a_{00} \pmod {\langle x, y \rangle } \in \mathbb{C}$

Is my approach correct? What can I improve?

Comment: Note it's injective and surjective and you're done. For future reference, isomorphism theorems are friends.

Comment: @anon Do we have to prove that it's injective and surjective? Do you mean we could use a isomorphism theorem to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is pretty much the first isomorphism theorem: given a ring homomorphism $\phi : R \to S$, we have the isomorphism
$$
\frac{R}{\ker(\phi)} \cong \text{im}(\phi).
$$
So to write out what you thought a bit more explicitly, take $\phi : \Bbb C[x,y] \to \Bbb C$, with
$$
\phi\left(\sum_{m,n=0}^k a_{mn}x^my^n\right) = a_{00}.
$$
Then the kernel of $\phi$ consists of all the polynomials with no constant term, that is, $\langle x,y \rangle$. The image of $\phi$ is clearly the whole of $\Bbb C$, so the result follows from the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Can you explain more the sentence " the kernel of $\phi$ consists of all the polynomials with no constant term, that is, $\langle x,y \rangle$ " ?

Comment: The kernel of $\phi$ means everything in $\Bbb C[x,y]$ that is mapped to $0$. This means all the polynomials where $a_{00}$, the constant term, is zero. In other words, all non-zero terms of these polynomials *must* involve $x$ and/or $y$, hence $\langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: Thnaks for the answer! I appreciate it!